# TFS Workflow States

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I have a team that has requested that I create a Change Request WIT and Modify it to have 18 states. I'm fairly sure it's doable but is there a better way? The states do make sense to me. They are as follows:
 Proposed
 Requirements
 Req Review
 Designer CL
 AAR
 Detail Design
 Dev Peer Review
 TA Review
 Coding / Unit Test
 Code Review
 Promote to SIT
 QA Testing
 Promote to UAT
 UAT Testing
 Prod Deploy Prep
 Deploy
 Post Imp
 Closed

Am I asking for trouble by doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? You could check link [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/process/customize-process-workflow] for VSTS, and link [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/reference/change-workflow-wit] for on-premise TFS.

Comment: Which process template are you using? Is the team doing for example Scrum or Agile? What problems are your foreseeing?

Comment: We are using TFS 2015 update 3 (on prem)  a 3rd party integrator created the current process that we use, but it started from CMMI process. On of my fears is that an upgrade could break it. The other is now that I have created some new WITs and modified the proces template, how to export what is in TFS (current WITS and updated processes) so that I can use them to create new projects?

Comment: @PatDelaney If you're considering making extensive customizations, [review how the changes you make will impact maintenance and upgrade of your team projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/on-premises-xml-process-model#before-you-customize). If you want to download process template, please refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/work-items/guidance/manage-process-templates